# Vuze azbuddy (Friends) Plugin Issues

Tags: java, plugins, bittorrent, vuze

My Vuze Plugins menu from the application menu does not open.  Should it**?**  I'd like to utilize the [Friends](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Friends) plugin.  It is enabled, unloaded (green) and shows version 1.0 in Tools/Options/Plugins.  I do not have an azbuddy folder under ~home/.azereus/plugins/ and do not see an installer or source package available here: http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_list.php.

I've looked for hours through the vuze wiki and forum where there is not much dedicated to Linux.  I've tried enough random bits of troubleshooting from forums that a restart changes views or causes the main windows to show up blank, while I can still access the application menus.  A sudo apt-get remove vuze and sudo apt-get install vuze did not work.  Apparently there are several configuration files that would need to be removed to give it a fresh install.  Does anyone know where all of them are**?**  Are there any special instructions or order**?**

I like the idea of a private torrent share with friends.  Does transmission have that capability**?**

I'm posting this in the vuze forum with title: [Ubuntu azbuddy (Friends) Plugin Issues.](http://forum.vuze.com/thread.jspa?threadID=120492)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, The Vuze Plugins menu does not work when [installing](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Initial_Setup_Guide) from the Ubuntu software repositories.  There does not appear to be any support of the azbuddy plugin feature.  It is not offered from the Vuze [plugins list](http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_list.php) and a folder with configuration files is not adding automatically to `/home/username/.azureus/plugins`.  The Vuze GUI lists the plugin as installed and lets you configure it, but does not take affect.  Basically, it's just misleading.

Transmission does have the capability to privately share torrents with friends.  From the Transmission application menu select:

```
File/New
select the "Private torrent" check box.
```

There are just 2 directories where Vuze configuration files are stored (when installed using the repositories version rather than manually):

```
/home/username/.azureus
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/azureus:azureus.desktop
```

To completely uninstall, use the`purge`option. `autoremove`will get rid of any java packages you aren't using.  Until you log other users out, their configuration files will not be deleted.

```
sudo apt-get purge azureus
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

In conclusion, I've switched to Transmission and am happy.  Vuze doesn't seem to have much support and can be buggy.